# Is using fake details online allowed?

Tags: halal-haram, internet

Is using fake details online allowed? Sometimes companies ask for unnecessary information such as your phone number and sometimes they don't even need your name. Can I just put some fake details?

What about creating an online persona?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to upload your original details then why you are using that type of sites. And here you not clarifying which type of company you are talking about. And If this is job-related then you have to put your original details. If not then it depends on you. Using fake details for that because of security reason then it is OK. I think it is a matter of choice which depends on you.